# How can I overlay private files/folders over a public GitHub project working copy (and keep them under separate version control)?

Tags: git, github, version-control

For a public GitHub project, I have several script files (for running tests, generating documentation, uploading docs to a web server via scp etc.) which must not appear in the GitHub commits, but should be under version control in a local repository.

Example

```
-- src
 \- main
 \- test
 \- make <-- private
 build.xml <-- private
 build.sh <-- private
 scp-doc.sh <-- private
```

Currently I keep the 'private' documents in a separate (Subversion) repository, and have to copy them over to the Git working copy manually every time when I create a new branch (or when they change).

Q: is there a more elegant way to exclude these files from commits to the public GitHub repository, but keeping them under 'local-only' version control at this location?

Comment: I am linking files from a separate ("private") repository for those types of situations. You could also create a script that perform those links for you when creating a fresh clone, but I would also be happy to learn of a more elegant solution.

Comment: Rework your project so you have two subtrees, one public (on github) and one private.  Preferably next to each other, but you _may_ have one inside the other using submodules (which have pain points of its own).